# MSVC: Reading a specific 64 or 32 bit register (e.g. R10) in 64 bit code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

Is there any way with MSVC to read a specific 64 (or 32) bit register directly in a normal C++ function?

For example, can I read the contents of r10 somehow via any intrinsics or such?

---

For context:

I'm implementing a variadic function (lets call it my_func), which needs to forward its call to another variadic function, and add one more argument along the way (an ID if you will, any numeric type will do - a 16, 32 or 64 bit integer for example, doesn't matter too much).

I need to do this forwarding in as little instructions as possible, so I can't process the variadic list in the initial function and just forward the va_list or such.

So I've implemented my_func in assembly:

```
; This function needs to be as compact as possible
my_func PROC
  ; assume 123 is the ID to be passed along with the arguments that my_func is called with
  mov r10, 123 
  jmp address_of_the_real_target_function
my_func
```

I just jump to the target function, and pass the ID in a seperate register - R10 in this case.

```
ARG* the_real_target_function(ARG* arg0, ...)
{
    auto id = ReadRegister();
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

This works well so far - only nuisance being that I needed another assembly helper function to read R10 back in the proper C++ function,

```
ReadRegister PROC
  mov rax, r10
  ret
ReadRegister ENDP
```

which is a bit annoying as that call won't get inlined.

Hence the question - is there any way to read this register directly in C++?

(Otherwise, I was thinking of maybe utilizing SSE registers, which should be readable via intrinsics - but curious if there's a way to do this with just 64 - or 32 - bit registers)

Thanks

--

edit: I believe this is *not* a duplicate of the linked topic. Listed solutions in there are specific to other compilers, or in case os MSVC, 32-bit only (inline assembly is not supported on x64)

--

edit 2: For more context on why I'm trying to do this.

This is indended to be an Excel Addin (which will host plugins and expose their functions to Excel, basically).

In order to register a function in Excel, I need to bind it to a specific function exported by my DLL. I don't know in advance (= at compile time) how many, or what plugin functions need to be registered and called.
So I need to implement loads of exported functions - thousands. Enough to always have registration slots for all plugins available.

In order to keep the overall size of the DLL in check, I need the registered functions to be very slim, and ideally also be capable of dealing with variadic args (as I don't know what shape the plugin functions have at compile-time; and due to the space-constraints, I want to avoid creating callbacks for any possible aririty of arguments)

And for even more added fun, it needs to work in x64 and x86 - though in the latter case, the function is called by Excel via stdcall convention, so the usual C++ variadic args won't work. But, at least at runtime I can find out the number (and type) of args passed to the function, so I should be able to handle the stack myself.

So bottom line, my idea is to have these slim trampoline functions, which will forward all arguments, plus their ID, to some central handler (as per above in X64; and via stack in X86).

The handler then gets things a bit into order - i.e. creates some standardized iterator for the arguments, calls the actual plugin function registered via that ID etc.

Comment: @SergeyA  This is not a duplicate of the linked to question. Inline assembler does not work for X64 targets in MVC. [Inline Assembler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=vs-2017). `Inline assembly is not supported on the ARM and x64 processors.`

Comment: I am curious why you need to pass the argument in a register. Can you provide more details about the business domain problem you are trying to solve with this particular technical approach? I am wondering if there is some other technical approach that would solve your business domain problem.

Comment: So you're trying to use a custom calling convention that passes another arg in R10?  That's far beyond what you're asking: you're asking for a way to get the register value on function entry, not at some random point *within* a function, after the compiler might have already clobbered it, because it doesn't know about your custom calling convention.  I think GCC has a way to modify the calling convention, or at least it's open source so you could always make a custom gcc version.  But don't expect dynamic linking trampolines to respect / preserve R10.  No hope of doing this safely with MSVC.

Comment: @RichardChambers Sure, I'll fill in some details in the original post in a minute

Comment: @RichardChambers yeah, agreed. Wasn't aware of this limitation. Side note: a dupe close could be prevented by OP by showing research efforts (as always encouraged) and indicating that the obvious dupe doesn't solve their problem because of that limitation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, good point indeed...I would not expect this to touch R10, as real_target_function effectively just processes the args into a va_list and then forwarsd that again to another function (which is decorated with noinline), BUT you're certainly right that is an issue / there are no guarantees for that. Maybe I'd be best off implementing the 2nd stage function in ASM as well

Comment: If you're happy to test carefully and inspect the generated asm every build, then sure you could use this and it will *probably* keep working for most surrounding code.  As long as nobody hooks your function with a trampoline that uses R10 as a tmp.  Otherwise, maybe if you have the ultimate caller pass a dummy arg that your wrapper *replaces*, that would work reliably.  If it's one of the first 4, it's in a register already.  Ideally the first, so the real args are still contiguous after spilling them to the shadow space.

Comment: you need pass *pointer* to arguments stack - so single parameter, instead variable from your generic hook/stub. and can of course easy use additional arguments here. you not need use `r10` or another register. you ask about how implement your not best solution , instead ask about initial problem

Comment: @RbMm That depends though, the initial function might be called with just few (zero, or one, or two or such) parameters, meaning by x64 convention the next parameter would have to be in a register instead of on the stack. So modifying the proper calling convention doesn't seem practical here. I could of course just generally use the stack instead of R10, but though that would equate to a custom calling convention as well - so not sure if that'd be much of a benefit (I'd assume it might even mess up the parameters of the_real_target_function)

Comment: @Bogey - no, you mistake, in the stack reserved place for first 4 parameters. so we need `mov [rsp+8],rcx 
mov [rsp+10h],rdx 
mov [rsp+18h],r8 
mov [rsp+20h],r9
lea rcx,[rsp+8]` this is usual situation when function with vaargs called another function and pass pointer to args array. look how say `swprintf` call `vswprintf`. in *c++* for this used `__va_start(&argList, n)` which force compiler put rcx..r9 registers in stack and return address of stack to `arglist`. if you use asm code - do this yourself. not need change calling convention. and you not need use `r10`

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, did not know this is what va_start does so that's interesting/helpful in either case! Will have a look at this as well, though expect it's possible these 5+ extra instructions may add some strain on the size again (moving va_start and jus passing va_list resulted in too large a DLL) - either way, happy to  try & appreciate the input!

Comment: @Bogey what you ask here is classic [XY](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) problem. this is usual situation when function with vaargs call another function - passed *all* vaargs and additional parameters. in this case always *pointer* to vaargs passed as parameter. for [example] (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/vswprintf/) 4 additional instruction for push rcx,rdx,r8,r9 to reserved place to stack is nothing really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static thread_local` variable would take few instructions, so it is not that slim as you may want. 
Yet it would be fully portable.

There's less portable but more instruction-efficien way.
Notice Arbitrary data slot in [TEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block). 
So `__readfsdword(0x14)`/`__writefsdword(0x14)` on x86 and `__readgsqword(0x28)`/`__writegsqword(0x28)` on x64 may do this trick. If, well, no one else is using the same extra space for other purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about thread locals as well initially, but (for size reasons) I try to do without the CRT, which seemed to rule out standard thread locals from some initial tests. The latter might be very interesting though, I'll have a look at that - thanks a lot!

Comment: TlsSetValue / TlsGetValue is Windows TLS, this would work without CRT